# Mongoose .sort breaks .skip & .limit

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

So i've implemented infiniscroll with mongoose and my query looks like this

```js
const posts = await Seed.find({status: 'APPROVED', 'color.name': color})
  .skip(parseInt(skip) || 0)
  .limit(8)
  .exec()
```

**That works great, from 0 to the end of posts.** However if i add .sort({upvotes: -1})

```js
const posts = await Seed.find({status: 'APPROVED', 'color.name': color})
  .sort({upvotes: -1})
  .skip(parseInt(skip) || 0)
  .limit(8)
  .exec()
```

Everything goes nuts, i can get the same post 6 times.

I've stared at this for hours now and i simply cannot understand why this is happening and it feels like a bug.

I've tried .sort('-upvotes'), .sort({upvotes: 'desc'}), .sort({'upvotes': 'desc'})

**Update: Sorting by .sort('-date') actually works, so i'm having a problem with upvotes specifically. The majority of posts has 1 upvote. Does mongoose randomize then? Sounds really strange if it did**

If anyone can help me figure this out i would be very thankful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically your question is similar to pagination.

Because your multiple documents contain same value of `upvotes`, mongo does not able to recognise the difference(between same values) and can give same document over and over.

For example your suppose your `limit` is `2` and following are your documents.

```
[{
  upvotes: 1,
  doc: "a"
}, {
  upvotes: 2,
  doc: "b"
}, {
  upvotes: 2,
  doc: "c"
}, {
  upvotes: 3,
  doc: "d"
}]
```

Now if you use `sort` with `upvotes: -1` and `limit` `2`

You might get at first page

```
[{
  upvotes: 3,
  doc: "d"
}, {
  upvotes: 2,  // here mongo fails to make difference
  doc: "c"     // document c
}]
```

or can give

```
[{
  upvotes: 3,
  doc: "d"
}, {
  upvotes: 2,  // here mongo fails to make difference
  doc: "b"     // document b
}]
```

Means mongo randomly throws the documents having same `sort` field value.

Solution is too simple here just put `_id` accordingly

```
const posts = await Seed.find({ status: 'APPROVED', 'color.name': color})
  .sort({upvotes: -1, _id: -1 })
  .skip(parseInt(skip) || 0)
  .limit(8)
  .exec()
```

Comment: @ Ashh can you please answer to this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77118285/reactjs-and-mongoose-infinite-scrolling-implementation-issue